# Take an existing gem, modify it, and ship with my own Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

What's the best way to take an existing gem and ship it with my own modifications in a Rails 3 application? Right now I simply copied the directory over from my local `rvm` cache, and modified the source where it needs to be modified. I can put it into `vendor/` and add the `:path` in Gemfile. The problem is, I have to write my own gemspec and worry about that as well. Is there a tool out there that makes this easier? Another method of going about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this gem is already on Github, I think you could just fork this on Github, modify this in the way you need it and then in your Gemfile just put:

```
gem 'name_of_the_gem', :git => "git://github.com/name_of_your_account/name_of_the_gem.git"
```

Comment: Not just github, bundler would install the gem from *any* valid git url, as long as the `.gemspec` file is in order.

Comment: Yes, but I gave here Github as example.

Comment: do not forget to send pull request to original author too :)

Comment: @MichałCzapko - Well thats what I am trying to say. The question is not about github, right?

Answer (score 1):

How big are your modifications? If it's something small, I would just override the methods in an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `gem install your_gem.gemspec` replacing your_gem with the name of the gem you are working on and then do `bundle package`. That should put the new Gem in your vendor cache.